# User management in android studio flutter

Tags: flutter

```
class UserManagement {
  storeNewUser(user, context) async {
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('/users').add({
      'email': user.email,
      'uid': user.id,
    }).then(() {
      Navigator.of(context).pop();
      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed(HomePage.id);
    }).catchError((e) {
      print(e);
    });
  }
}
```

trying to store user data and this error [The argument type 'Null Function()' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'FutureOr Function(DocumentReference<Map<String, dynamic>>)'.] came up please help me solve it